# morris.js - line chart with json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, morris.js

**Here are my resources:**

- pageviews.json
- myfile.html

**My pageviews.json file contents:**

```
[
    {"day":1,"pageviews":"687928"},
    {"day":2,"pageviews":"688331"},
    {"day":3,"pageviews":"603741"},
    {"day":4,"pageviews":"542002"},
    {"day":5,"pageviews":"657730"},
    {"day":6,"pageviews":"804183"},
    {"day":7,"pageviews":"776029"},
    {"day":8,"pageviews":"654589"}
]
```

**I am trying to render a morris.js line chart with:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("pageviews.json", function (json) {
    var jason_data = JSON.stringify(json);
    var jasonstuff = (jason_data.replace(/\"/g, "")); 

    Morris.Line({
      element: 'mydiv',
      data: jason_data,
      xkey: 'day',
      ykeys: ['pageviews'],
      labels: ['PageViews']
    });
  });
});
```

**the var jasonstuff outputs JSON sans the quotes.**

```
[{day:1,pageviews:687928},{day:2,pageviews:688331},{day:3,pageviews:603741},{day:4,pageviews:542002},{day:5,pageviews:657730},{day:6,pageviews:804183},{day:7,pageviews:776029},{day:8,pageviews:654589}]
```

**The error I get:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

This seems to fall apart at the `xkey` and `ykeys` values. I know I **MUST** be missing something really dumb. Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: FYI, json is not someone's name (Jason), it stands for JavaScript Object Notation. Your variable names gave me a chuckle. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be stringifying the data returned from `.getJSON()`. Nor should you be trying to replace quotes. You've misunderstood the difference between a JSON string and a native Javascript object.

Morris expects a Javascript object (or an array of objects). Your `pageviews.json` is technically one big string. What `.getJSON()` does is fetch that file and convert it from a string into a native object.

```
var myString = '{"day":1,"pageviews":"687928"}';
var myObject = {day: 1, pageviews: "687928"};
```

By stringifying the data returned from `.getJSON()` you're actually converting the native object back into a string again, which Morris doesn't understand. The quotes aren't the issue either, other than they have to be there in the string in order for it to be considered valid JSON format. Just feed the JSON object returned by `.getJSON()` directly into Morris.

```
$.getJSON("pageviews.json", function (json) {
  Morris.Line({
    element: 'mydiv',
    data: json,
    xkey: 'day',
    ykeys: ['pageviews'],
    labels: ['PageViews']
  });
});
```

NOTE: your `pageviews: "687928"` attribute is storing the number as a string in your `pageviews.json` file. You may want to convert that within the file before reading it into your application, otherwise you'll need to parse the value (unless Morris does that for you).

Answer (score 0):

Here data is an array of objects, containing x and y attributes as described by the `xkey` and `ykeys` options. Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HGKyw5hSs8KtGoM0KvYd?p=preview)

```js
var data=[
    {"day":"1","pageviews":"687928"},
    {"day":"2","pageviews":"688331"},
    {"day":"3","pageviews":"603741"},
    {"day":"4","pageviews":"542002"},
    {"day":"5","pageviews":"657730"},
    {"day":"6","pageviews":"804183"},
    {"day":"7","pageviews":"776029"},
    {"day":"8","pageviews":"654589"}
]


Morris.Line({
  element: 'mydiv',
  data: data,
  xkey: ['day'],
  ykeys: ['pageviews'],
  labels: ['PageViews'],
  parseTime : false
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/morris.js/0.4.1/morris.min.js"></script>
    
      <div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your json i generate chart 
Please find below link and check

[Morris chart](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPwjyR)

I jsut try below code and its works fine

```
 var jason_data = [{day:1,pageviews:687928},{day:2,pageviews:688331},{day:3,pageviews:603741},{day:4,pageviews:542002},{day:5,pageviews:657730},{day:6,pageviews:804183},{day:7,pageviews:776029},{day:8,pageviews:654589}];

Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: jason_data,
  xkey: 'day',
  ykeys: ['pageviews'],
  labels: ['PageViews']
});
```